# When reading date columns in excel files using pandas do we need to specify year?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have this python script

```
 import pandas as pd

 def main():
    readExcelFile()

def readExcelFile():
    fileName = "abc.xlsx"
    data = pd.read_excel(fileName,engine='openpyxl')
    print(data['Date'])
    data['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],format='%mm/%dd')
    print(data['Date1'])

main()
```

My date column in the excel file looks like this

```
    12/01
    12/02
    12/03
    12/04
```

etc

But when I print it out as a pandas dataframe it looks like this

```
    2001-12-01
    2002-12-01
    2003-12-01
    2004-12-01
```

The input date that is present in the Excel file is not matching with the pandas date obtained from the data frame. The date type is correct it is datetime64[ns].

It is appending the year to date data but there is no year information in the Excel file.

Based on useful information from @cottontail in the comments my modified question - should an excel file containing date data columns contain the year information as well ? I have no use to do date differences of any sort. I am reading in the excel data and plotting it.
.

Comment: @cottontail The input and output date formats should be identical. I just want to use same format as is in the excel file. They are not matching currently. The excel file format is `%mm/%dd`

Comment: @cottontail You can go ahead and write it up. I have modified my question title and content slightly.